# jQuery - Using ajax JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I'm using jquery to get the data from the following API (https://swapi.co/api/people/).

So far, I can get all the main data, "name", "height", "mass" etc.

But, when I try to get the values ​​of "homeworld", "films", "species", "vehicles", "starships" it only shows the url to which it refers, I do not know what method I should use to obtain the values ​​within these URLs .

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getStarWars() {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      async: true,
      url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/1/',
      success: function(datos) {
        if (datos != null) {
          console.log(datos.name);
          console.log(datos.homeworld);
          console.log(datos.films);
          console.log(datos.species);
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, status) {
        alert('Sorry, i have a problem');
      }
    });
  }

  getStarWars();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But the data is correct? Upon checking the api, the value for the homeworld is 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/' which you got the correct one.

Comment: But.. the values ARE the urls, no?!

Comment: The data is correct. I just checked and the api returns the url for homeworld and films. If you want to show the information of homeworld. You need make another GET call using the homeworld url that is returned in datos. Same goes for films and species too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the ajax in a separate function and call it everytime a url needs to be processed

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getData(url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      async: true,
      url: url,
      success: function(data) {
        callback(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status) {
        alert('Sorry, i have a problem');
      }
    });
  }

  function getStarWars() {
    getData('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/', function(data) {
      console.log(data.name);

      getData(data.homeworld, function(planet) {
        console.log(planet.name);
      });

      data.films.forEach(function(film) {
        getData(film, function(film) {
          console.log(film.title);
        });
      });

      getData(data.species, function(species) {
        console.log(species.name);
      });
    });
  }

  getStarWars();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-fetch the data of that new link

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getStarWars() {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      async: true,
      url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/1/',
      success: function(datos) {
        if (datos != null) {
          console.log(datos.name);
          console.log(datos.homeworld, 'asdasdasd');
          console.log(datos.films);
          console.log(datos.species);
          getStarWarsNew(datos.homeworld)
        }

      },
      error: function(xhr, status) {
        alert('Sorry, i have a problem');
      }
    });
  }

  function getStarWarsNew(URL) {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      async: true,
      url: URL,
      success: function(datos) {
        if (datos != null) {
          console.log(datos);

        }

      },
      error: function(xhr, status) {
        alert('Sorry, i have a problem');
      }
    });
  }

  getStarWars();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```